# Programa PYTHON que imprima en pantalla los números que van desde el triple hasta el doble de un número, en orden descendente

Tags: python-3.x

Primero gracias de antemano por vuestro tiempo. Soy muy novato (2 semanas)

Tengo que escribir un programa que solicite al usuario que introduzca un número entero mayor que 0 e imprima en pantalla los números que van desde el triple hasta el doble de dicho número, en orden descendente.

El **problema** es que no sé como mostrar los números que hay entre las dos variables de doble y el triple.

```
number = int(input('Número: '))
doble = int(number*2)
triple = int(number*3)

print (triple)

for i in range(doble,triple):
    print (i)

print (doble)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes usar bucles y matematica o (si lo tienes permitido) la función [range](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/functions.html#func-range).

Comment: Si el problema es cómo mostrar, usa `print(x)`. Pero sospecho que el problema es cómo ir calculando esa `x` y cómo saber cuándo parar. Yo usaria bucles `while`. Ya que se trata de un ejercicio (posiblemente una tarea) para pedir ayuda deberías mostrar qué has intentado y dónde te has atascado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución:

```
number = int(input('Número: '))
doble = number*2
triple = number*3

for i in range(triple, doble - 1, -1):
    print (i)
```

`number` ya es un entero; no necesitas volver a aplicar `int` para obtener el doble y el triple.

Para recorrer en orden inverso usas `range` con todos sus parámetros:

```
range(start, stop, step)
```

En este caso:

- start Es el valor inicial, `triple` en este caso.
- stop  Es el valor final, que sería `doble - 1`, pues se detiene al llegar a ese valor. Si no restas 1, se detendrá antes de procesar `doble`.
- step  Es cuanto sumas/restas a `start` para llegar a `stop`. Default es 1, pero como vas decreciendo, pones `-1` para ir restando.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario!! Funciona perfectamente. Aunque he de decir que me cuesta entender el doble -1, -1. Miraré algún tutorial. Gracias!!!!

Comment: @JoséFeijóoReverter. La iteración termina cuando la variable de rango llega al valor "stop". Por lo tanto, no procesa el último valor (20 en el ejemplo). Entonces, tienes que correr en uno hacia abajo. Juega con los valores y veras.